# Hive parse string to columns

Tags: hive, hiveql

In a Hive table, I have columns (all have string datatype)

CustomerId, Name, Gender

Name datatype is string of format

```
{'firstname': 'XXXXXX', 'middlename': 'YYYYYY',  'lastname': 'ZZZZZZ'}
```

Also, some of the rows have missing middlename -

```
CustomerId, {'firstname': 'AAAAAA', 'lastname': 'BBBBB'}, Gender
```

I wanted to create a new table and populate the below columns -

```
CustomerId, firstname, middlename, lastname , Gender.
```

Middlename will be null/spaces if value not present. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Those are not valid JSON strings, use double quotes instead of single quotes, then you may use `JSON_TUPLE()` to extract fields.

```
CREATE TABLE yournewtable AS
 SELECT customerid,
       firstname,
       middlename,
       lastname,
       gender
FROM yourtable lateral view 
  json_tuple(Name,'firstname','middlename','lastname') 
j as firstname, middlename,lastname;
```